# Putting Special Character in Excel column header gives error

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am using OpenXML library for creating the Excel file and there I am adding a special character asterisk (*) after column name in header to show the mandatory fields for some columns. But it seems to be not working as it is affecting its behavior and gives me error when I download it for importing data.

below is the error snap. -

[image]

This error affects the data in excel and therefore I am unable to perform certain operations like binding and selecting list values using DropDown in excel column which also affect the import process.
[image]
My question is, How I can allow special character (*) in column header of excel using OpenXML?

Below is the code where I am passing Import Column names (including *)

```
public ImportField Owner = new ImportField("Owner", ImportField.DataTypes.String, false, 50);
public ImportField BusinessUnit = new ImportField("Business Unit*", ImportField.DataTypes.String, true, 100);
public ImportField AccountNo = new ImportField("Account Number", ImportField.DataTypes.String, false, 100);
public ImportField LastName = new ImportField("Last Name*", ImportField.DataTypes.String, true, 50);
public ImportField FirstName = new ImportField("First Name*", ImportField.DataTypes.String, true, 50);
public ImportField Department = new ImportField("Department*", ImportField.DataTypes.String, true, 50);
public ImportField Title = new ImportField("Title*", ImportField.DataTypes.String, true, 50);
public ImportField BusinessPhone = new ImportField("Business Phone", ImportField.DataTypes.String, false, 20);
public ImportField MobilePhone = new ImportField("Mobile Phone", ImportField.DataTypes.String, false, 20);
public ImportField Fax = new ImportField("Fax", ImportField.DataTypes.String, false, 20);
public ImportField Email = new ImportField("Email*", ImportField.DataTypes.String, true, 100);
public ImportField Address1 = new ImportField("Address 1", ImportField.DataTypes.String, false, 100);
public ImportField Address2 = new ImportField("Address 2", ImportField.DataTypes.String, false, 100);
public ImportField City = new ImportField("City", ImportField.DataTypes.String, false, 50);
public ImportField State = new ImportField("State", ImportField.DataTypes.String, false, 20);
public ImportField Zip = new ImportField("Zip", ImportField.DataTypes.String, false, 15);
```

ImportField Constructor:

```
private void ImportField(string excelColumn, DataTypes dataType, bool required, int length, string sheetName)
{
    ExcelColumn = excelColumn;
    DataType = dataType;
    Length = length;

    Required = required;
    SheetName = sheetName;                              

    if (dataType == DataTypes.Boolean)
    {
      DataTable dtYesNo = new DataTable();
      dtYesNo.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(Boolean));
      DataRow dr = dtYesNo.NewRow();
      dr["Value"] = true;
      dtYesNo.Rows.Add(dr);
      dr = dtYesNo.NewRow();
      dr["Value"] = false;
      dtYesNo.Rows.Add(dr); 

      this.PickTable = dtYesNo;
      this.PickList = true;
      this.PickListField = "Value";
    }
}
```

Excel Create Method:

```
public void Create(string fileName, List<string> sheetNames, List<ImportFileBase.ImportField> fields, bool addErrorColumn)
{
  //Open the copied template workbook. 
  using (SpreadsheetDocument myWorkbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(fileName, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
  {
    ExtendedFilePropertiesPart extended = myWorkbook.AddExtendedFilePropertiesPart();
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = myWorkbook.AddWorkbookPart();

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.ExtendedProperties.Properties properties1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.ExtendedProperties.Properties();

    ApplicationVersion applicationVersion1 = new ApplicationVersion();
    applicationVersion1.Text = "12.0000";

    properties1.Append(applicationVersion1);
    extended.Properties = properties1;

    // Create Styles and Insert into Workbook
    var stylesPart =
        myWorkbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
    Stylesheet styles = new CustomStylesheet();
    styles.Save(stylesPart);

    var workbook = new Workbook();
    var fileVersion =
        new FileVersion
        {
          ApplicationName = "Microsoft Office Excel"
        };

    if (sheetNames != null)
    {
      //create a sheet for each one specified in the list
      var sheets = new Sheets();

      //create validation lists first
      if (sheetNames.Contains("ListValues", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
      {
        WorksheetPart listValuesSheet = this.CreateLookupWorksheetPart(workbookPart, fields);
        AddWorkSheetPart(listValuesSheet, workbookPart, sheetNames, "ListValues", sheets, true);
      }

      ///add import sheet
      foreach (string name in sheetNames)
      {
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = null;
        if (!name.Equals("ListValues", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
          worksheetPart = this.CreateDataWorksheetPart(workbookPart, fields, addErrorColumn);

        AddWorkSheetPart(worksheetPart, workbookPart, sheetNames, name, sheets, false);
      }

      //add file version and sheets to workbook
      workbook.Append(fileVersion);
      workbook.Append(sheets);
    }
    //add all defined Names for validation lists
    if (_definedNames != null)
      workbook.Append(_definedNames);

    myWorkbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = workbook;
    myWorkbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
    myWorkbook.Close();
    myWorkbook.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Appreciate your thoughts on same.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code you're working with?

Comment: @Dortimer added code snippet